# Aggregate two javascript event functions

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hello everybody and sorry for this question, but I'm not a javascript expert.

I'm trying to add the cookie alert box to my website, and I want to set the cookies when a user click on a button and when he scrolls the page after 50 pixels. I write this two functions but I cannot understand how to chain them!

```
$(document).ready( function(){
  $('.cookies-eu-ok').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $.cookie('cookie_eu_consented', 'true', { path: '/', expires: 365 });
    $('.cookies-eu').remove();
  });
});

$document.scroll(function() {
  if ($document.scrollTop() >= 50) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.cookie('cookie_eu_consented', 'true', { path: '/', expires: 365 });
    $('.cookies-eu').remove();
  }
});
```

Comment: I think, your ready function should cover even scroll fn

Comment: Why do you want to chain them, they are essentially doing the same thing? Or would you rather avoid to have duplicate code? Then you should use a function

Comment: Please tell me the exact problem you are facing.

Comment: I want to avoid duplication in my code :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what you can do:

```
var setCookie = function() {
    $.cookie('cookie_eu_consented', 'true', {
        path: '/',
        expires: 365
    });
    $('.cookies-eu').remove();
};

var $document = $(document); // Caching
$document.ready(function() {
    $('.cookies-eu-ok').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        setCookie();
    });
});

// Run only once until cookie is set
$document.on('scroll', function(e) {
    if ($document.scrollTop() >= 50) {
        e.preventDefault();
        setCookie();
        $document.off('scroll');
    }
});
```

1. Creating separate function for common functionality
2. Chaining the events on same elements
3. Caching `$(document)`
4. Using `on` instead of `click`. `Click` calls `on` inside

Comment: The callback to `scroll` should have the `e` parameter

Comment: I'd rather remove `e.preventDefault();` from scroll handler, since there is nothing to prevent there. It will probably add some problems with scrolling being disabled

Comment: @KremnevSergey Not sure about that. OP has used it, so I've kept it

Comment: Don't know if OP wants to be re-setting the cookie every single time the `scroll` event is triggered and the page is > 50px from the top..

Comment: @AlexMcMillan Good Point! It depends on the value OP wants to set. Doesn't look like it is changing per scroll, Updating.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a function that can be shared among handlers (for simplicity, DRY etc) like this:

```
function saveConsentCookie () {
    $.cookie('cookie_eu_consented', 'true', { path: '/', expires: 365 });
    $('.cookies-eu').remove();
}
```

and you can setup your handlers for the 2 events like this:

```
$(document).on({
    ready: function () {
        $('.cookies-eu-ok').click(function (e) {
            saveConsentCookie();
            e.preventDefault();
        })
    },
    scroll: function scrollCheck () {
        if ($(this).scrollTop() >= 50) {
            saveConsentCookie();
            $(this).off('scroll', scrollCheck);
        }
    }
});
```

Note that the `scroll` handler function has a name (`scrollCheck`) so that it can be removed once it has done its job.  Without this, your page would be checking if it needs to set the cookie forever...